# How do I put a pair of parentheses on each matched line with Python regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to convert the following code

```
print "*** Dictionaries"
dictionaries = json.loads(api.getDictionaries())
print dictionaries
...
print(bestMatch)
...
```

to

```
print("*** Dictionaries")
dictionaries = json.loads(api.getDictionaries())
print(dictionaries)
...
print(bestMatch)
...
```

that is, to put a pair of parentheses on each `print` line.

Here is my code

```
import re

with open('p2code.txt') as f:
  lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

cmplr = re.compile(r'(?<=print).*')

p3code = []

for line in lines:
  p3line = line
  m = cmplr.search(line)
  if m:
    p3line = 'print(' + m.group(0) + ')'
  p3code.append(p3line)

with open('p3code.txt', 'w') as f:
  for line in p3code:
    f.write(f"{line}\n")
```

There're 2 questions related to the code above.

Is there a more elegant way to do the replacement, e.g. `cmplr.sub`? If yes, how do I do that?

one of the `print` lines has already put the parentheses

```
print(bestMatch)
```

How do I make my code skip that line, avoiding something like

```
print((bestMatch))
```

The idea/need comes from Cambridge's API doc
https://dictionary-api.cambridge.org/api/resources#python

Comment: Can you just include the space after `print` in the lookbehind to avoid the parenthesis? `re.sub(r'(?<=print )(.*)', r'(\1)', s))`

Comment: Are you trying to convert python2 code to python3 code? Your python installation should ship with a tool that does this: `2to3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do it with a single command at the command line using [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). Something like:

```bash
sed -i -E 's/print ([^\(].*[^\)])/print\(\1\)/g' code.py
```

This is both minimal and easy. But in case you're pressed on doing it with python, you can make use of the following:

```py
re.sub("print ([^\(].*[^\)])", r"print($\1)", lineOfFile)
```

You can play with the regex further [here](https://regex101.com/r/mrLAED/2).